# Centering a div in a list item

Tags: css, html, centering

I have an html page in which I have a div inside a list item and trying to center the div in the list item (the div's width is smaller than the list item's width). My CSS looks like

```
ul.my {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 0;
}

li.my {
    list-style: none;
}

div.content {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And the HTML has a snippet that looks like

```
<li class="my"><div class="content">stuff</div></li>
```

But the div is left aligned. How can I properly center align it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either horizontal-center the content of the div with

```
div.content {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

or center the div itself:

```
.my li {
    text-align: center;
}
div.content {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

For vertical centering, you'll have to wrap the `display: table-cell` element in a `display:table` one, like

```
.my li {
    height: 200px;
    display: table;
}
div.content {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: @JeffStorey Updated with a concrete example. Yes, the li (or a wrapper around the div) must have `display:table`.

Comment: if you need browser support for IE7, `display:table` won't work ([specs](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp))

Answer (score 0):

Is your css and html really related?

your `.my` class is on the `li` element, so your styling should look like:

```
li.my {
  // li styles
}
```

and unless you have a larger container around your `ul` then `.my ul` doesn't apply here either.

Aside from those changes, either use `li { text-align: center; }` or `div { margin: auto; }`

UPDATE (vertical centering):

For vertical centering, if your text is all on one line, then try setting your `line-height` to the same size as your `font-size`, like:

```
div.content {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
}
```

It's a bit trickier if it wraps onto 2 or more lines.  [Try this](http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/).

Comment: Oops, typo there. That is fixed. Is there a way to vertically center the content in the div?

Comment: There are multiple lines, but the solution that @phihag proposed worked.